# 'Project.exe has triggered a breakpoint.'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, memory-management

I am working with C++ and OpenCV on Visual Studio; for my application, I have a set of images and a `.mask` one that permits to select a ROI in each of them (it is 0 everywhere but in the ROI).

I load the images (`duck1.jpg`, `duck2.jpg`, etc.) with:

```
std::array<cv::Mat, n_imgs> img;
std::string folder = "C:/Users/imgs/";
std::string fname = "duck";
std::string format = ".jpg";

for (int i = 0; i < n_imgs; i++)
    img[i] = cv::imread(folder + fname + std::to_string(i + 1) + format, 0);
```

Then, I apply a mask:

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::imread(folder + fname + ".mask" + format, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < img[0].rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < img[0].cols; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < n_imgs; k++)
            if (mask.at<float>(i, j) == 0)
                img[k].at<float>(i, j) = 0.f;
```

I keep getting 'Project.exe has triggered a breakpoint.' quite randomly in some recurring points of my successive code (which I won't post here because is quite long); however, these problems disappear when I comment the masking line.

Given the symptoms, I supposed it is an allocation problem, am I right? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure your mask is the same size as your first image? Are you sure that all your images are the same size? That's what your code is assuming.

Comment: What is the stop reason?

Comment: Yes, I verified that both checking the files directly and by debugging; also, I use Image Watch to take track of what happens to `cv::Mat`s, and that should not be a problem. It is true that I should probably add some error handling, for now I have been neglecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be more of a guess what is wrong but I will give you a hint.

Are you sure that `img` have float as underlying type? Because when you do `cv::imread(file, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE )` this 0 stand for gray scale image which usually is CV_8UC1 (unsigned char of 8 bit) when you address it with float (which has size of 32 bit) you may end up writing memory after the end of image (24 bits after last pixel in image are written). This may sometimes trigger error and sometimes not, it depends on what is in memory after your image (is it allocated or not). I guess that if you run your program in Debug mode it will always fail.

So change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < img[0].rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < img[0].cols; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < n_imgs; k++)
            if (mask.at<float>(i, j) == 0)
                img[k].at<float>(i, j) = 0.f;
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0; i < img[0].rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < img[0].cols; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < n_imgs; k++)
            if (mask.at<unsigned char>(i, j) == 0)
                img[k].at<unsigned char>(i, j) = 0;
```

If you want your code to run faster and you have binary mask (with values of 0 and 1) you can just multiply these element-wise like this (note that this is only for one image):

```
cv::Mat afterApplyMask = img.mul(mask);
```

Comment: That's right, thank you! I know it's a stupid thing, but I'm quite used to OpenCV in Python, so these kind of details always screw me up.

Comment: Glad that I helped :)

Answer (score -1):

I was writing a C code in Visual Studio when I encountered this error. My project name and name of the solution in the source file was the same. Once I changed those and debugged, I stopped encountering the error.